# Popovercontroller is automatically resizing

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, resize, uipopovercontroller

in my App i have a Longpress Gesture on my TableCell. On Lonpress a Popover opens. The Popover inerhits a NavigationController.
Here is the code:

```
var navigationController = new UINavigationController();

//Page 1 
var contPage1 = new UIViewController();
this._movePicker = new UIDatePicker();
var btnPage1 = new UIButton();
btnPage1.Frame = new RectangleF(0,260, 300,40);
contPage1.View.AddSubview(this._movePicker);
contPage1.View.AddSubview(btnPage1);

//Page 2
var contPage2 = new UIViewController();
var btnPage2 = new UIButton();
var textField = new UITextField();
textField.Frame = new RectangleF(0,35,300,150);
btnPage2.Frame = new RectangleF(0,260,300,40);
contPage2.View.AddSubview(btnPage2);
contPage2.View.AddSubview(textField);

// startPopover
this.PopoverController = new UIPopoverController(navigationController);
this.PopoverController.PopoverContentSize = new SizeF(300,340);
//Navigate on the first site
navigationController.PushViewController(contPage1, true);
btnPage1.TouchUpInside(s,e) => navigationController.PushViewController(contPage2, true);

this.PopoverController.PresentFromRect(locationinView, btn, UIPopoverDirection.Any, true);
```

Okay. This works fine. A popover appears. on the FirstView i click on the button and it navigates me to the second page. After that the keyboard appears and i can write something in the textField. If i close the keyboard the popover changes his size. It now takes the entire height of the iPad´s display.

But why does it resize. I set the size of the Popover to 300, 400